# making a rock, paper, scissors code in python. SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement

Tags: python

this is my code:

```
import random
import time

validInput = False


computer = (random.choice(["rock", "paper", "scissors"]))
batman = input("welcome to rock, paper, scissors would you like to play: yes or no?"
if batman == "yes":
         choice = input("okay, these are the rules: I will say, rock, paper, scissors, shoot and then I will ask you what you picked and then tell you who won - are you ready to play: yes or no?")
         if choice == "yes":
            while validInput = False:
              time.sleep(1)

              print("rock")
              time.sleep(1)

              print("paper")
              time.sleep(1)

              print("scissors")
              time.sleep(1)

              print("shoot")
              time.sleep(1)

              what = input("what did you pick")
              if what == "rock" and computer == "rock":
                  print("I picked rock too, I guess we drawed")
                  fudge = input("do you want to play again: yes or no?)
                  if fudge == "yes":
                     print("restarting program")
                     continue
                  if fudge == "no":
                     print("okay, terminating program")
                     exit()
                  else:
                     print("invalid input, terminating program")
                     exit()
              if what == "rock" and computer == "paper":
                  print("I picked paper, so I guess I won better luck next time")
                  fudge = input("do you want to play again: yes or no?)
                  if fudge == "yes":
                     print("restarting program")
                     continue
                  if fudge == "no":
                     print("okay, terminating program")
                     exit()
                  else:
                     print("invalid input, terminating program")
                     exit()
              if what == "rock" and computer == "scissors":
                  print("I picked scissors, I guess you win")
                  fudge = input("do you want to play again: yes or no?)
                  if fudge == "yes":
                     print("restarting program")
                     continue
                  if fudge == "no":
                     print("okay, terminating program")
                     exit()
                  else:
                     print("invalid input, terminating program")
                     exit()
              if what == "paper" and computer == "paper":
                  print("I picked paper, so I guess we drawed")
                  fudge = input("do you want to play again: yes or no?)
                  if fudge == "yes":
                     print("restarting program")
                     continue
                  if fudge == "no":
                     print("okay, terminating program")
                     exit()
                  else:
                     print("invalid input, terminating program")
                     exit()
              if what == "paper" and computer == "scissors":
                  print("I picked scissors, so I guess I won better luck next time")
                  fudge = input("do you want to play again: yes or no?)
                  if fudge == "yes":
                     print("restarting program")
                     continue
                  if fudge == "no":
                     print("okay, terminating program")
                     exit()
                  else:
                     print("invalid input, terminating program")
                     exit()
              if what == "paper" and computer == "rock":
                  print("I picked rock, so I guess you won")
                  fudge = input("do you want to play again: yes or no?)
                  if fudge == "yes":
                     print("restarting program")
                     continue
                  if fudge == "no":
                     print("okay, terminating program")
                     exit()
                  else:
                     print("invalid input, terminating program")
                     exit()
              if what == "scissors" and computer == "scissors":
                  print("I picked scissors, so I guess we drawed")
                  fudge = input("do you want to play again: yes or no?)
                  if fudge == "yes":
                     print("restarting program")
                     continue
                  if fudge == "no":
                     print("okay, terminating program")
                     exit()
                  else:
                     print("invalid input, terminating program")
                     exit()
              if what == "scissors" and computer == "rock":
                  print("I picked rock, so I guess I won better luck next time")
                  fudge = input("do you want to play again: yes or no?)
                  if fudge == "yes":
                     print("restarting program")
                     continue
                  if fudge == "no":
                     print("okay, terminating program")
                     exit()
                  else:
                     print("invalid input, terminating program")
                     exit()
              if what == "scissors" and computer == "paper":
                  print("I picked paper, so I guess you won")
                  fudge = input("do you want to play again: yes or no?)
                  if fudge == "yes":
                     print("restarting program")
                     continue
                  if fudge == "no":
                     print("okay, terminating program")
                     exit()
                  else:
                     print("invalid input, terminating program")
                     exit()
              else:
                  chicken = input("invalid input, do you want to try again: yes or no?")
                  if chicken == "yes":
                      print("restarting now")
                      invalidInput = False
                      continue
                  if chicken == "no":
                      print("okay, terminating program")
                      invalidInput = True
                      exit()
                  else:
                      print("invalid input, terminating program")
                      invalidInput = True
                      exit()


         if choice == "no":
               print("okay terminating program")
               invalidInput = True
               exit()
         else:
             print("invalid input, terminating program")
             exit()

if batman == "no"
   print("okay, terminating program")
   exit()

else:
   print ("invalid input, terminating program")
   exit()
```

i don't know why it isn't working all it tells me is

SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement.

could someone please help thank you.

Oh also i'm running python on 3.6.0

Comment: `while validInput = False:`: `= != ==`

Comment: the highlighting here shows that you are missing a closing quote after: `fudge = input("do you want to play again: yes or no?)`

Answer (score 2):

- In the while loop you are making an assignment, not a comparison, change `=` to `==`.
- Every time you use `fudge()` there are missing quotes at the end.
- At the end, you have `if batman == "no"` where it should have been `if batman == "no":` (note the two points).